# Problemas com tag em arquivos CSS num projeto JSF2

Tags: css, jsf-2.2

Saudações para todos,

gostaria que olhassem a imagem a baixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês podem notar que existe um topo de cor azul com um menu Horizontal, ele está atrelado á essa tag abaixo no XHTML;

```
<header>

<div style="float: right; margin-right: 110px">
    <span
        style="float: left; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; margin-right: 60px">
        Olá usuário! </span>

    <h:form style="display: inline-block">
        <p:menubar styleClass="menu-sistema">
            <p:submenu label="Cadastros">
                <p:menuitem value="Usuários" />
                <p:separator />
                <p:menuitem value="Empresa" outcome="/empresa/CadastroEmpresa" />
                <p:menuitem value="Clientes" outcome="/cliente/CadastroCliente" />
                <p:menuitem value="Categorias" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Pesquisa">
                <p:menuitem value="Pesquisar Clientes" outcome="/cliente/PesquisaCliente"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Pesquisar Empresas" outcome="/empresa/PesquisaEmpresa" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Tarefas">
                <p:menuitem value="Adicionar Tarefas" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Sair" />
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>

</header>
```

E com essa configuração no CSS

```
header {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;

    background-color: #4169E1;
    color: #fff;

    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ccc;
}
```

Não existe nada de errado na pagina XHTML e nem no CSS, mas estou enfrantando um  problema estranho.

Eu sempre fiz paginas de internet nos meu projetos acadêmicos utilizando CSS com HTML, mas eu colocar as configurações de CSS num projeto JSF2 começo a enfrentar problemas de configuração de CSS, eu criei as tag´s na pagina XHTML com CSS e não funciona nada, vou dá um exemplo, vou pegar o mesmo exemplo mostrado anteriormente e modificar-lo, sabemos que quando vamos colocar na pagina HTML como

```
<div id="topo"></div>
```

na pagina CSS vai ser

```
 #topo
```

Até aqui beleza, vou substituir a tag  por  e ficará assim.

```
<div id="topo">

<div style="float: right; margin-right: 110px">
    <span
        style="float: left; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; margin-right: 60px">
        Olá usuário! </span>

    <h:form style="display: inline-block">
        <p:menubar styleClass="menu-sistema">
            <p:submenu label="Cadastros">
                <p:menuitem value="Usuários" />
                <p:separator />
                <p:menuitem value="Empresa" outcome="/empresa/CadastroEmpresa" />
                <p:menuitem value="Clientes" outcome="/cliente/CadastroCliente" />
                <p:menuitem value="Categorias" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Pesquisa">
                <p:menuitem value="Pesquisar Clientes" outcome="/cliente/PesquisaCliente"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Pesquisar Empresas" outcome="/empresa/PesquisaEmpresa" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:submenu label="Tarefas">
                <p:menuitem value="Adicionar Tarefas" />
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Sair" />
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>

</div>
```

E no CSS vai ficar assim;

```
#topo {
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;

    background-color: #4169E1;
    color: #fff;

    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ccc;
}
```

Na verdade era para continuar funcionando, mas não é o que acontece, veja o que aconteceu;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele simplesmente não funcionou.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira diferente de programar as paginas XHTML em projetos JSF2 para o CSS

Pelas alterações que fiz era para continuar funcionando, porque eu somente alterei o nome da tag, nada mais.

Comment: Você tem certeza que ele esta carregando o arquivo de css do #topo?

Comment: O que poderia impedir de carregar no css o #topo?

Comment: O que eu quis dizer é se o caminho da importação está correto.

Comment: a pagina xhtml está lincado correto com o arquivo CSS. você quer que eu coloque o código inteiro da pagina xhtml mais um print do projeto para mostrar aonde estár o CSS? eu acho que não precisa, mas se você quiser eu coloco.

Comment: tente colocar como classe ao invés de usar o #id

Comment: Ele pego certinho, mas agora eu gostaria de saber porque isso acontece?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25673/discussion-between-wladyband-and-rafael-ferreira).